# Reopening of a wrong duplicate question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I've been browsing SO and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50385188). The user clearly didn't know how to ask his question, and probably does not know how to find the actual problem, but I found out that this problem is more than a simple [NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384).

I understand why it has been closed, as the guy asked a question about a symptom of the problem and not the problem itself. However, I believe this question might be useful to many people if edited and well answered. I can edit the question to match SO's question style better, but I can't reopen it obviously. What can/should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist that the question was closed wrongfully, then you can

- [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50385188/edit) the question to improve it (as you propose); and then
- [vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) to reopen the question, or ask a question on Meta tagged [reopen-closed](/questions/tagged/reopen-closed), or ask in [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/).
  <sub>Since you have less than 3 000 reputation, voting to reopen won't work. That would be the preferred option though.</sub>

Also see [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36415)

Comment: I didn't know I could vote to reopen, I only got implied in SO recently. I'll go do what you proposed :)